# C - Printing first letter of a string using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

Im currently working on a project for college and i have the following function, which receives a line (string) and divides it into words:

```
static const char separators[] = {' ','\t',',',';','.','?','!','"','\n',':','\0'}; 

void split(char *line){
    char *token = strtok(line, separators);
    while(token!=NULL) {
        strtolower(token);
        printf("%s \n", token);
        /* rest of code belongs here */
        token = strtok(NULL, separators);
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I wanted to print the first letter of the string `token`, however it prints the whole string and whenever i use other methods `(*token, token[0])` it creates an error stating that `%s` expects type `*char` and not `int`.

How can i print only the first letter of the string, for future implementation in my code?

Comment: You do know that there are other format specifiers for `printf()` other than `%s`?

Comment: You're right, stupidity of me... i've only been recently leaning C and i forgot that i coul use %c and *token. Thank you

Comment: you should accept the answer from @Carey Gregory as it is correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very simply:

```
printf("%c\n", *token);
```

or

```
printf("%c\n", token[0]);
```